# Cannot access geolocation inside of function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now. I have three functions that all work in isolation. However, I cannot get the value from `getUserCoordinates()` to appear in `fetchCurrentTemp()`. It returns `undefined` no matter what I attempt. I've been outside of the JS environment for a minute, so perhaps I am missing something obvious but i am stumped.

**fetchCurrentTemp()**

```
import { getUserCoordinates } from './helpers';
const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5';

export const fetchCurrentTemp = async () => {
    const coordinates = getUserCoordinates();
    console.log('coords:', coordinates);
    // logs 'undefined'
    try {
        let response = await fetch(`${url}/weather?APPID=x&lat=50.7498752&lon=-100.0004158&units=imperial`);
        let output = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

**getUserCoordinates()**

```
export const getUserCoordinates = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({ coords }) => {
            console.log(coords);
            //returns a value
            return coords;
        });
    } else {
        alert('Something is wrong');
    }
};
```

**App**

```
import React from 'react';
import { fetchCurrentTemp } from './utils/api_calls';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => fetchCurrentTemp()}>Hello</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `return coords`, **you are merely returning out of the callback function**, not out of `getUserCoordinates()`.

You can use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)-based approach since `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous:

```js
export const getUserCoordinates = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({ coords }) => {
                console.log(coords);
                resolve(coords);
            });
        } else {
            reject('Something is wrong');
        }
    });
};
```

And then modify `fetchCurrentTemp()` to include `await`:

```js
// --snip--
const coordinates = await getUserCoordinates();
// --snip--
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to return a promise on the `getUserCoordinates`. Otherwise, the return result will always be undefined.

Take a look on the example pen: https://codepen.io/lessadiogo/pen/ZEYqXRa

Cheers,